# WSO2DSS batch insert with JSON data

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

Using WSO2 DSS 3.5.1 I'd like to find a JSON format for inserting multiple records

having resource

```
<resource method="POST" path="/insert/count">
    <call-query href="insert_rawdata">
      <with-param name="timeslot" query-param="timeslot" />
      <with-param name="cell_id" query-param="cell_id" />
    </call-query>
</resource>
```

and query

```
<query id="insert_rawdata" useConfig="PG_DB">

    <sql>INSERT INTO mobile_data (  date_time , timeslot , cell_id  ) 
        VALUES (
           NOW()::timestamp, :timeslot::timestamp with time zone, :cell_id )
      ON CONFLICT (timeslot, cell_id) DO NOTHING </sql>
    <param name="timeslot" sqlType="STRING" type="IN"/>
    <param name="cell_id" sqlType="INTEGER" type="IN"/>
</query>
```

it's pretty straightfoward to POST multiple records with XML

```
<test_list>
   <data>
    <timeslot>2017-11-13 14:00</timeslot>
    <cell_id>1234</cell_id>
  </data>
   <data>
    <timeslot>2017-11-13 14:00</timeslot>
    <cell_id>1235</cell_id>
  </data>    
</test_list>
```

Reading the documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS351/Using+JSON+Messages+with+RESTful+Services looks useful, however seems the documentation is not right

according to the documentation the JSON object should be `_post$RESOURCE`, but it's `_post_$RESOURCE`

working POST request:

```
{ 
  "_post_insert_count" :  {
        "timeslot": "2017-11-13 14:00",
        "cell_id": 1234
  }
}
```

however I am unable to find correct JSON syntax/format to POST (insert) multiple records with single request, according to the documentation should be

```
{   "_post_insert_count_batch_req": { 
    "_post_insert_count": [
        {
        "timeslot": "2017-11-13 14:00",
        "cell_id": 1234
        } ,
        {
        "timeslot": "2017-11-13 14:00",
        "cell_id": 1235
        }] 
}
```

then I got an exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.GsonXMLStreamReader.validateArgumentTypes(GsonXMLStreamReader.java:783)
    at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.GsonXMLStreamReader.nextValue(GsonXMLStreamReader.java:734)
    at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.GsonXMLStreamReader.readValue(GsonXMLStreamReader.java:626)
```

so - someone could help to build a valid JSON request for inserting multiple records?

Thanks for any hint

Answer (score 0):

working example:

```
{ 
"_post_insert_items_batch_req": {   
"_post_insert_items": [{
  "timestamp": "2017-11-13 14:00:00",
  "school": "Regina Pace",
  "eventid": 1234
  },
  {
  "timestamp": "2017-11-13 14:00:00",
  "school": "Regina Pace",
  "evenid": 1235
  }

  ]
}
}
```

which is strange as last time I had NPE from similar request, so I don't really understand where's the problem